# Debugging RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool from arcpy.RasterDomain_3d()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, 3d-analyst

I´m always getting an Error with my Python-Code. Even though it is almost the same as on the ArcGIS Help Website.

The Error occurs in line 19:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:_geodata\check.py", line 19, in
>
> arcpy.RasterDomain_3d(rasterList,out_file,geometry)
>
> File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\ddd.py", line 998, in RasterDomain
>
> raise e
>   RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
>
> Failed to execute (IterateRasterDomain).

My Code looks like this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()

if rasterList:
    for raster in rasterList:
        geometry = "POLYGON"
        out_file = "domain_" + raster[:-4] + ".shp"
        arcpy.RasterDomain_3d(rasterList,out_file,geometry)
    print "Finished"
else:
    print "No Data available"
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
 to make sure it is [Available?](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003q000000).

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps "rasterList" should be "raster" in:

```
arcpy.RasterDomain_3d(rasterList,out_file,geometry)
```

From the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q90000007s000000) it looks like RasterDomain_3d takes only a raster rather than a list.

Comment: Thank you Cyrus. That really was the problem. Seems like I overlooked it